# Behaviour of single and double quotes depending on shell

Tags: bash, tcsh, csh, ack

I've been scratching my head for quite some time with this....

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67484388/8543838), I'm trying to run 'ack' and to find either a single quote or a double quote in source files.

Doing this in **bash** perfectly works:
`ack --cpp "['\"]"`

But doing the same in **tcsh** gives me: `Unmatched ".`

One of the alternatives I have tried is to essentially swap the single and double quotes, leading to `ack --cpp '[\'"]'`. But I'm still getting the same `Unmatched ".`

No matter what I try, I don't seem to be able to get the wanted behaviour in tcsh.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: tcsh treats backslash in doublequotes as data. Use `"['"\"]` or (sledgehammer) `\[\'\"]`

Comment: `"['\"]"` appears to work in tcsh 6.20.00 if the `backslash_quote` variable is set

Comment: All 3 proposals work for me, thanks a lot ! Out of curiosity though, it's not clear to me how the first two work.... The way I read `"['"\"]` is that the inner "\" is considered as backslash. which then leaves `"[` on the left and `]` on the right... Is there not a (closing) double quote missing ? As for `\[\'\"]` the way I read it is that all characters are essentially escaped except the last one (why `\[` but `]` without escape ?)

Answer (score 0):

From [dave-thompson-085](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/59699/dave-thompson-085)'s comment:

> tcsh treats backslash in doublequotes as data. Use `"['"\"]` or (sledgehammer) `\[\'\"]`

From [steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver)'s comment:

> `"['\"]"` appears to work in tcsh 6.20.00 if the backslash_quote variable is set